# ¿Cómo ver el data label en Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, chart.js

Necesito mostrar el data label en un pie_chart.

Tal como lo muestra la imagen manipulada manualmente.
[image: pie_chart]

en mi código tengo lo siguiente:

en `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'chartkick',                        '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'highcharts-rails',                 '~> 6.0.3'
```

en `application.js`:

```
//= require highcharts
//= require chartkick
```

en `inicio_controler.rb`:

```
@datos  = [["Muestra A", 4],["Muestra B", 7],["Muestra C", 13],["Muestra D", 2]]
```

en la vista:

`index.html.erb`:

*Ya he intentado estas cuatro versiones y ninguna camina:*

**VERSION 1**

```
<%= pie_chart    @datos, label: 'true' %>
```

**VERSION 2**

```
<%= pie_chart    @datos, library: {plotOptions: { pie: { dataLabels: { enabled: true }}}} %>
```

**VERSION 3**

```
<%= pie_chart    @datos, dataLabels: "Value" %>
```

**VERSION 4**

```
<%= pie_chart    @datos3, dataLabels: "true" %>
```

Comment: ¿pero algún error o mensaje de advertencia en la consola del server o del browser? ¿has inspeccionado el html donde debería insertar el gráfico para ver si hay algo? Veo [en la doc.](https://chartkick.com/#installation) que estás usando las indicaciones para sprockets y no webpacker ¿esto es correcto? ¿has probado no agregar ninguna opción?

Comment: saludos estimado lagos, si, lo instale con las indicaciones para sprockers, no hay ningun mensaje de error o algo parecido en la consola del servidor ni en el browser y si, he probado sin ninguna opcion, de hecho fue la primera y nada.

Comment: He probado en un proyecto que tengo corriendo con rails 4.2 el agregar la gema y el código en gral. tal cual pusiste, probé las 4 versiones y [no me dio problemas ninguna de ellas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js5t2.png). Supongo algo más debe ser que no has puesto aun en la pregunta.

Comment: ese es el resultado exacto que me da, igual que el tuyo, pero lo que yo quisiera es tener cada valor fij en cada porcion el pie.

Comment: ‍♂️ mis disculpas, entendí mal la pregunta. Pensé que no te estaba mostrando nada en pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la doc de `highcharts`, podrías alinear los labels con un [`distance`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) negativo y cambiar la info con [`format`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.format) (mas opciones de formateo [en la doc](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)).

```
<%= pie_chart @datos, library: {
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
        distance: -50
      }
    }
  }
} %>
```

esto da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

*Consideración fuera del alcance de esta pregunta*: Podrías evaluar el no usar gemas intermediarias, como `chartkick`, para manejar librerías js. Creo que es agregar más carga a la app rails y tu `Gemfile` de algo que no le atañe, aparte que en muchas ocasiones (no parece ser el caso con `chartkick`) están bastante desactualizadas respecto a la librería js original. Es uno de los objetivos de `webpacker`, pero usando `sprockets` igual podrías conseguir esto manteniendo un `package.json` en la raíz de tu proyecto y agregar [una nueva carpeta de assets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23194493/895789) en `vendor/` (que quede ignorada en tu control de versiones), donde puedas agregar la versión exacta de `chartkick` que usas.

Comment: Amigo Lagos, excelente, eso es justo lo que necesito, me parece interesante eso que me propones donde o como puedo ver o descargar la libreria js?, para poder quitar la gema chartkick?

Comment: Está lleno de tutoriales allá afuera. Por ejemplo (aquí hay uno)[https://g3ortega.com/rails/2017/05/30/rails-5-1-and-forward-yarn-on-rails.html] para usar `yarn` para instalar las nuevas librerías, en la parte que dice "Yarn on Rails" sale en algunas líneas lo que deberías hacer. Saludos